# JVM running out of memory exception in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I can't use  any processor  becuase it throws exceptions and when i want  to clear connection queues  it  trows excepton like this:0 FlowFiles (0 bytes) were removed from the queue.

Failed to drop FlowFiles due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot update repository because all partitions are unusable at this time. Writing to the repository would cause corruption. This most often happens as a result of the repository running out of disk space or the JVM running out of memory.

Answer (score 4):

In this scenario it sounds as if your disks are full. You can raise the amount of heap allocated to the JVM running Apache NiFi with the Java args in `bootstrap.conf`.

```
# JVM memory settings
java.arg.2=-Xms4096m
java.arg.3=-Xmx8192m
```

It is generally recommended to keep the [content repository](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#content-repository), [provenance repository](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#provenance-repository), and [flowfile repository](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#flowfile-repository) on different disks and allocate a healthy amount of storage for each. You can configure the maximum size for each in `nifi.properties` to cause them to age out data faster.